# Как обработать объект в рекурсии, чтобы можно было найти среднее значение JS

Tags: javascript

Как правильно обработать объект в рекурсии, чтобы можно было найти среднее значение value?
часть объекта

```
var graph = {
    value: 75,
    children: [{
        value: 18,
        children: [{
            value: 35,
            children: [{
                value: 35,
                children: [{
                    value: 66,
                    children: [{
                        value: 29,
                        children: [{value: 85}]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var graph = {
    value: 75,
    children: [{
        value: 18,
        children: [{
            value: 35,
            children: [{
                value: 35,
                children: [{
                    value: 66,
                    children: [{
                        value: 29,
                        children: [{value: 85}]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}

function sum(data, result) {
  result.add(data.value);
  (data.children || []).forEach(i => sum(i, result));
}

var d = { 
  sum: 0, 
  count: 0, 
  add: function(v) { this.sum += v; this.count++; },
  ave: function() { return this.sum / this.count; } 
};

sum(graph, d);
console.log(d.ave());
```